# Disappearing of div on small screens

Tags: html, css

Disappearing of div on small screens.

That Div should be shown in two parts if the screen gets small.

In small screen, div is not visible.

[Visit](http://namarsaham.website.tk/) & see down the countdown, it disappears on small screen.

How to fix it?

The code goes here:-

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Maintenance in Progress
</title>
<style>
.timer {
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  right: 500px;
  bottom: 0;
}
body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.utxt{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.circle{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.dtxt{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 30%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body background="maintenance/bg.png">
<img class="utxt" src="maintenance/utxt.png"></img>
<img class="circle" src="maintenance/circle.png"></img>
<img class="dtxt" src="maintenance/dtxt.png"></img>
<div class="timer" id="demo"></div>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("May 19, 2017 00:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me!

Comment: Position is fixed and right 500px must be bigger than your width. What do you want to acomplish?

Comment: You have to redefine your styles for different screen sizes using @media or you can use twitter bootstrap for reponsiveness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your requirement the code goes here:-

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Maintenance in Progress
</title>
<style>
.timer {
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  right: 500px;
  bottom: 0;
}
.stimer {                   <!--added-->
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  right: 500px;
  bottom: 60px;
}
.bstimer {                  <!--added-->
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  right: 500px;
  bottom: 0;
}
body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.utxt{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.circle{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.dtxt{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 30%;
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {             <!--added-->
    .timer {
       display: none;
    }
    .stimer {
       right:0;
    }
    .bstimer {
       right:0;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 900px) {         <!--added-->
    .stimer {
       display: none;
    }
    .bstimer {
       display: none;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body background="maintenance/bg.png">
<img class="utxt" src="maintenance/utxt.png"></img>
<img class="circle" src="maintenance/circle.png"></img>
<img class="dtxt" src="maintenance/dtxt.png"></img>
<div class="timer" id="demo"></div>
<div class="stimer" id="sdemo"></div></br>          <!--added-->
<div class="bstimer" id="bsdemo"></div>             <!--added-->

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("May 19, 2017 00:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // Output the result in an element with id="sdemo"                  (added)
    document.getElementById("sdemo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h ";

    // Output the result in an element with id="bsdemo"                 (added)
    document.getElementById("bsdemo").innerHTML = minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope I helped you out!

Answer (score 0):

Remove Right:500 and fixed position!! It pushes your clock outside the screen!!
To make it centred:

```
display:table
margin: auto
```

Try:

```
<img class="circle" src="maintenance/circle.png">
<div class ="bottomLine">
    <img class="dtxt" src="maintenance/dtxt.png">
    <div class="timer" id="demo">7d 9h 21m 35s </div>
</div>
```

Try to hold dtxt and timer together (display:inline, or sth.) Than set "bottomLine" to center, for example and bottom:0. Do not use fixed position, to prevent overlapping divs to eachother :)

Answer (score 0):

It's is because you gave the countdown a `right:500;` , you need to remove this on smaller screens like this:

```
@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .timer {
       right:0;
    }
}
```

**Note**: you have to put this at the bottom of your stylesheet

Comment: Why media queries? They are not useful in this case. It's just a matter of simple horizontal centering.

Comment: @Emonadeo your answer doesn't even solve the problem, so maybe fix your own answer first.....

Comment: Thanks it helped me out, somewhere

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the `right: 500px;` in your CSS.
Change it to percentage or add a media query for smaller screens so that you can adapt it as you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `right: 500px`. If your screen's width is `500px` or smaller the `div` moves out of range. (Makes sense, right?) Never work with absolute values if you want your website to be responsive. Instead do something like this:

```
.timer {
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> try this it will work fine for all screen

```
.timer {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 60px;
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
        right: 50%;/*change*/
        bottom: 0;
        margin-right: -181px;/*change*/
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your **position:fixed** to **position:absolute**